# Property of concyclic foci of hyperbola and it's conjugate hyperbola

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

I've been taught that a hyperbola of the form $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ has it's conjugate hyperbola simply as $\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=-1$

This also means that the conjugate hyperbola's eccentricity and foci distances are different from the original hyperbola.

The standard hyperbola's eccentricity is given as $\space e= \sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$

And so, the conjugate hyperbola's eccentricity is (also given by formula $\space \frac{1}{e1^2}+\frac{1}{e2^2}=1$ where e1 and e2 are eccentricities of original hyperbola and it's conjugate) $\space \space e2 = \sqrt{1+ \frac{a^2}{b^2}}$

Now, I was taught that a hyperbola and it's conjugate hyperbola's foci are concyclic, and form the vertices of a square. This is exactly where I get my doubt. I tried plotting some random hyperbola on a graph and then plotted it's conjugate and then tried to see if the foci really are concyclic, and here's what I got.

[image: Random Hyperbola]

I made the circle pass through the foci of the standard hyperbola, with P and Q being the foci of the original hyperbola $\frac{x^2}{16}-\frac{y^2}{9}=1$ and R and S being the foci of the conjugate. I found out the foci distance by the formula

c (length of foci from origin) = $ae$ for standard hyperbola

or $c = be$ for the conjugate hyperbola

As we see here, the foci aren't forming any square, nor are concyclic.

I request advice to know where I'm missing the mark.

Comment: @Natru: What "graphical explanation" do you expect? OP simply mis-calculated somewhere; without intermediate calculations, we can only guess about the error. ... OP *knows* the distances to the foci are $c_1=ae_1$ and $c_2=be_2$, where $e_1:=\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$ and $e_2:=\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{b^2}}$ (ie, $5/4$ and $5/3$). OP *could have* reduced algebraically to get $c_i=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ (ie, $5$) for both cases, but didn't. Instead, OP calculated $c_1=20/3$ and $c_2=15/4$. OP may have inadvertently swapped the $e_i$ ... or something else. No "graphical explanation" will solve that mystery.

Comment: I had made a miscalculation myself too, they do form a square. But a proof on why the focii are concyclic would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me where things are going wrong for you, but you have a lot of correct information.

Ultimately, you are correct that the distance $c$ from center to focus is given by $c = a e$ for the standard hyperbola, and by $c=be$ for the conjugate hyperbola. But be careful: you mean $c=ae_1$ and $c=be_2$, since the eccentricities differ. Notice what those calculations give: 
$$\begin{align}
\text{standard:}\quad c &= a e_1=a\;\sqrt{1+\frac{b^2}{a^2}}= a\;\sqrt{\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2}}=a\;\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \tag{1} \\[6pt]
\text{conjugate:}\quad c &= b e_2=b\;\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{b^2}}= b\;\sqrt{\frac{b^2+a^2}{b^2}}=b\;\frac{\sqrt{b^2+a^2}}{b}=\sqrt{b^2+a^2} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
Since $(1)$ and $(2)$ match, the standard and conjugate foci are all equidistant from the origin; thus, they are the vertices of a square, and they must lie on a common circle. $\square$

So, I would guess that something is wrong with your Desmos entries, but I'm not currently in a position to pick through those details. You might consider using [GeoGebra](http://geogebra.org), where you can enter the algebraic formulas for the hyperbolas but also construct them geometrically via their foci, and see if the results match.

Answer (score 1):

Hope the Geogebra sketch explains all your questions. Main/conjugate hyperbolae constructed with major/minor axes.

$$(4,5);\, (3,5);$$

The central rectangle should be drawn. Their eccentricities

$$e_1= AC/AG ;\, e_2= AC/AF ;\quad  \frac{1}{e_1^2}+\frac{1}{e_2^2}=1\,$$

The concyclic foci $I,H$ and the other two axis mirrored foci are seen on a circle.

[image: HypblaSEM]

Answer (score 0):

Th3 foci of the horizonal Hyperbola are at $H_1,H_2=(\pm ea,0)$ and yhose of bertical ones are $V_1,V_2=(0,\pm bE)$. Here $$e=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{a},~~ E=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}{b}$$
$O(0,0)$ being the center the concyclicity of$ H_1,H_2,V_1, V_2$ demands that
$$OH_1.OH_2=OV_1.OV_2 \implies a^2e^2=b^2E^2= (a^2+b^2),$$
and this is true.